# opencv copy one matrix into the first column of another matrix

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, matrix

I have a vector of pointers whcih are pointing to a image (size w=96 h=100 NoImg=100) that I got from my camrea and framegrabber. az you see I am creating matrix of them and start reading the data one by pixel. the next step is to create a bigger matrix(h=9600 w=100) which can hold all the pixels data of one image in the first column, and the next image data to second column, but the time that I reach to the 100 of images.
I was wondering is there any sufficient way or pre ready method in opencv , that helps me to copy all the image data to the one column of another matrix directly?? or do I need to read all the pixels one by one, like my code at below and write them one by one inside another one? 
**Edit**
I end up with the following code

```
cv::Mat _mainMatrix(_imageSize,_totalImgNO,CV_8UC1);    
//loop for creating a matrix of each image in the memory
for(counter=0;counter<_totalImgNO;counter++){
    unsigned char* _pointer=(unsigned char*)_imgPtrVector.at(counter);
    cv::Mat _matrixImage(cv::Size(width,height), CV_8UC1,_pointer , cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);         
    channels=_matrixImage.channels();
    nRows=_matrixImage.rows * channels;
    nCols=_matrixImage.cols;
    if (_matrixImage.isContinuous())
    {
        nCols *= nRows;
        nRows = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
    {
        p = _matrixImage.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int  j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
        {
            if(iRow<_totalImgNO && jCol<_imageSize){                
                _mainMatrix.at<uchar>(iRow,jCol)=p[j];
                iRow++;
            }               
        }
    }
    jCol++;
    iRow=0; 
    _matrixImage.~Mat();            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is really close to the reshape function.

Tell me if I'm wrong :)

[Opencv Reshape](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#Mat%3a%3areshape)

Comment: well I just check it, I dont think this is useful, cause I need to add all the images matrix in to one big matrix then I can implement my algorithm.

Comment: Well, I would at least use it in your first step, to fit all your images into one line. Then, point each img.data to the beginning of each line of your final image.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV iterators are STL iterators. That means, you can use STL functions on them.

Rough example:

```
cv::Mat1b bigmat(9600, 100);
for (int i = 0; i < bigmat.cols; ++i) {
    cv::Mat1b column = bigmatrix.col(i);
    cv::Mat1b &source = *(images[i]);
    std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), column.begin());
}
```